# Select OK button from modal in testing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, testcafe

I'm trying to select an element on my page using testcafe, but I'm very inexperienced with selectors.  I'm happy to select it in the JSX or in the html, but can't figure out either method. After clicking the "LayerAddingPopUpButton", the modal is rendered on the page, so I try to click the OK button that appears at the bottom.  The test currently fails as it doesn't believe the modal OK button appears.

```
import { waitForReact } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';
import { ReactSelector } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';

fixture `App tests`
    .page('http://localhost:3000/')
    .beforeEach(async () => {
        await waitForReact();
    });

test('test layer adding pop up', async t => {
    await t
        .click('#LayerAddingPopUpButtonID');

    const modalOKButton = ReactSelector('ant-btn');
    await t.click(modalOKButton);
});
```

The JSX tree of the rendered page:
[image]

[image]

The html of the rendered page:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this code :

```
const modalOKButton = ReactSelector('ant-btn');
await t.click(modalOKButton);
```

by this:

```
const modalOKButton = Selector('div.ant-modal')
  .find('div.ant-modal-footer')
  .find('button.ant-btn-primary');
await t
  .expect(modalOKButton.with({visibilityCheck: true}).exists)
  .ok({timeout: 30000})
  .hover(modalOKButton)
  .click(modalOKButton);
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me a quick summary of why you decided to start at "div.ant-modal" and then use "find" to select sub elements?  This worked perfectly.

Comment: @Michael, when i can target a selector with an id or with a data attribute (like data-e2e="modalOKButton", the selector is : `const modalOKButton = Selector('[data-e2e="modalOKButton"]')`. It is a good practice to setup data-e2e attributes when you own the front code. If I cannot change front markup, I travel up through the DOM starting from the target field, until I found a unique path that has a self describing semantic: container1 -> sub-container2-> field. In your case: modal -> footer -> button. This self describing semantic makes the selector more readable and maintainable.